# How to handle method that throws plain Exception in try-catch

Tags: java, exception

Consider the following scenario: I have an object pool from which I (1) borrow an object, (2) do something with that object and then (3) have to return it to the pool. The challenge is that the first two steps may throw checked exceptions and step (1) even throws a plain `Exception`.

Let me show you the code I am currently using:

```
MyObject objectFromPool = null;
try {
    objectFromPool = pool.borrowObject(); // step (1), throws plain Exception   
    objectFromPool.doSomething();         // step (2), throws FailedToDoSomethingException
} catch (FailedToDoSomethingException e) {
    throw new MyCustomRuntimeException(e);    
} catch (Exception e) {
    // Now what? Did objectFromPool.doSomething() throw this exception or pool.borrowObject()?
} finally {
    if (objectFromPool != null) {
        pool.returnObject(objectFromPool); // step (3)
    }
}
```

Any suggestions how to handle the plain `Exception`? I don't want this code to throw a checked exception, because the caller wouldn't know how to handle it anyway. But I still want to differentiate between exceptions from `pool.borrowObject()` and `objectFromPool.doSomething()`, because the former indicates a "technical" exception and the latter a "business" problem.

Note: I neither control the code of `pool.borrowObject()` nor `objectFromPool.doSomething()`. Both are from external libraries and I have no idea what kind of `RuntimeException`s they might throw.

Comment: Why not use a specific (custom) exception? The caller (ie, your code) does know how to handle, as that is exactly what you want to do, and any other caller can still handle it using a ```catch(Exception)``` block if you make the specific exception a subclass of ```Exception```

Comment: I still don't know how to distinguish between exceptions thrown from `pool.borrowObject()` and `objectFromPool.doSomething()`.

Comment: How so? If ```pool.borrowObject();``` throws a ```FailedToBorrowException``` and ```objectFromPool.doSomething()``` throws a ```FailedToDoSomethingException``` you can distinguish perfectly by using two specific catch blocks.

Comment: I updated my question: I neither control the code of `pool.borrowObject()` nor `objectFromPool.doSomething()`.

Comment: Ahhhhhh, now I understand you better :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think the better way is to encapsulate the suspicious Exception into an specific exception which will fall into the eventual catch and finally:

```
    MyObject objectFromPool = null;
    try {
        try {
                objectFromPool = pool.borrowObject(); // step (1), throws plain Exception   
            } catch (Exception e) {
                // Encapsulate into an specific exception type:
                throw new MyOwnException(e);
            }
            objectFromPool.doSomething();         // step (2), throws FailedToDoSomethingException
        } catch (FailedToDoSomethingException e) {
            throw new MyCustomRuntimeException(e);    
        } catch (MyOwnException e) {
            ...
        } finally {
            if (objectFromPool != null) {
                pool.returnObject(objectFromPool); // step (3)
            }
        }
```

In this way, you could preserve your original catch and finally algorithm, having no doubt about where each exception come from.

One more thing: Remember that a Exception could be even a RuntimeException. Are you interested in catching RuntimeExceptions too? If not, add an extra catch to let them propagate:

```
        try {
                objectFromPool = pool.borrowObject(); // step (1), throws plain Exception   
            } catch (RuntimeException e) {
                // Let it propagate:
                throw e;
            } catch (Exception e) {
                // Encapsulate into an specific exception type:
                throw new MyOwnException(e);
            }
```

Comment: This seems to be the best idea so far, thanks! Although the nested try-catch doesn't make the code easier to read.

Comment: You are right. Well, you can wrap it into a private method.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to know which method call threw the exception, throw different exceptions from each method.

Based on your comments it seems that `doSomething` only throws `FailedToDoSomethingException`. If that's true, the only way to reach the second catch block (`catch (Exception e)`) is if `pool.borrowObject()` threw an `Exception`.

If both method calls can throw an `Exception` that is not a `FailedToDoSomethingException`, you must have more specific catch blocks in order to handle exceptions thrown by different methods differently. If you are throwing an instance of the base `Exception` class, you should consider throwing a more specific custom exception class instance instead.

Comment: Not quite: The `catch (Execption)` clause could be reached because `doSomething` had thrown a RuntimeException. :-(

Comment: Exactly, @LittleSanti, that is my problem. Plus: I neither control the code of `pool.borrowObject()` nor `objectFromPool.doSomething()`.

Comment: @hzpz If you want to handle RuntimeExceptions differently, add a third catch clause prior to the `catch (Exception e)` block. This way the last catch block will only catch checked exceptions.

Comment: That would be better in that I know that the `catch (Exception e)` block could only be reached by `pool.borrowObject()` throwing an exception. But I still wouldn't know which method caused the `RuntimeException`.

Comment: @hzpz Can both method throw the same type of RuntimeException? If not, you can differentiate using catch blocks of sub-classes of RuntimeException. If yes, and it makes a difference which method threw the exception, you can put each method in a separate try-catch block.

Comment: @Eran I updated my question. I have no idea what kinds of `RuntimeException`s those methods might throw.

Comment: @hzpz In that case, why do you care which of the method throws a RuntimeException? Are you going to handle it differently based on which method threw it? Are you going to handle it at all?

Comment: @Eran I would like to wrap every exception that `doSomething` throws in `MyCustomRuntimeException`. Exceptions thrown by `borrowObject` should just propagate. The difference being that `MyCustomRuntimeException` is a "business" exception, while any other `RuntimeException` is a "technical" problem.

Answer (score 0):

If both methods could throw plain `Exception` you could differentiate them by wrapping second method into new try/catch block:

```
try {
    objectFromPool = pool.borrowObject(); 
    try {
        objectFromPool.doSomething();
    } catch (Exception ex){
        // do something
    }  
} catch (Exception e) {
    // pool.borrowObject() throw this e
} finally ...
```

But if `objectFromPool.doSomething()` can throw only `FailedToDoSomethingException` follow **Eran**'s answer

Comment: The problem with this is, that I cannot throw an exception in the first catch block, because it would be caught by the second one.

Comment: You can try this. Actually there are lots of variants how to do this.
`} catch (MyCustomRuntimeException e) {
    // objectFromPool.doSomething() throw this e
} catch (Exception e) {
    // pool.borrowObject() throw this e`

Answer (score 0):

How about:

```
MyObject objectFromPool = null;
try{
    try {
        objectFromPool = pool.borrowObject(); // step (1), throws plain Exception   
    } catch (Exception e) {
        // pool.borrowObject has thrown exception
    }
    try {
        objectFromPool.doSomething();         // step (2), throws FailedToDoSomethingException
    } catch (FailedToDoSomethingException e) {
        throw new MyCustomRuntimeException(e);    
    }  

} finally {
return pool.returnObject(objectFromPool); // step (3)
}
```

(Edited as you mentioned you want to always do `pool.returnObject(objectFromPool);`.

Another way would be to make a finally block for each seperate try-catch block instead of this overarching try-finally block.

Comment: I have to return the object no matter what to prevent a memory leak, so I'd rather do this in a finally block.

Comment: Edited my answer to take this requirement into account. This is one way of a number of ways to do this. Other ways are described in the other examples.

Comment: Thanks, this is indeed another way of handling the exceptions. But it features even more nested try-catch blocks.

Answer (score 0):

You can't change the code of the methods you call and both of them can throw a plain `Exception`. Good new is you can distinguish which method threw the exception via the stacktrace:

```
MyObject objectFromPool = null;
try {
  objectFromPool = pool.borrowObject();
  objectFromPool.doSomething();
} catch (FailedToDoSomethingException e) {
  throw new MyCustomRuntimeException(e);    
} catch (Exception e) {
  //here we get the method name from the first element in the stack trace
  //this way we can identify the method that actually threw our exception
  if(e.getStackTrace()[0].getMethodName().equals("borrowObject")) {
    //pool.borrowObject threw the exception
  } else if (e.getStackTrace()[0].getMethodName().equals("doSomething")) {
    //objectFromPool.doSomething() threw the exception
  }
} finally {
  if (objectFromPool != null) {
    pool.returnObject(objectFromPool);
  }
}
```

You can even extend this by comparing `getClassName()` from the stacktrace.

Keep in mind that this may be prone to errors in case of refactoring. If you change the name of one of these methods the `if` clause may fail, in case you forget to change the name here.

Comment: Another interesting idea, thanks! Although it kind of feels like a hack.

Comment: It depends. I'm not a friend of using exceptions for the program flow and I don't know what you need to do different dependent on the method which threw the exception - there may be many valid reasons to do so - but I think this is the best and most-readable method to just distinguish where the exception came from. Thats quite far from being "hacky", imo ;)